# My Android application requires permissions I didn't request

Tags: android, android-permissions

I've just created a very simple Android application that captures an Intent, manipulates it a bit, and sends out a new Intent. I transferred the app to my phone with `adb install`, and now  looking at the app's requested permissions, I'm seeing that it requires permissions I never asked for:

- read phone status and identity
- modify or delete the contents of your USB storage
- test access to protected storage

There's nothing in my manifest file requesting permissions, and the app itself is dead simple ([here's the source on GitHub](https://github.com/tommcdo/skipper)). Are these extra permissions added because I installed it with `adb install`, perhaps? Or is there something in my app that merits requiring these permissions that I'm just not seeing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a `<uses-sdk>` element with `android:minSdkVersion`. These permissions were added to Android after its initial release, and apps supporting very old Android devices have these permissions "grandfathered in".

You really should add `<uses-sdk>` and add `android:minSdkVersion`, saying how old of an Android device (from an API level standpoint) you are willing to support.